Function to swap top right and bottom left squares in an n x n matrix
Given an n x n matrix, swap elements situated in two squares : top right and bottom left.
As it is more an academic task, we can restrict size to 10x10.
Moreover, we can't have extra space and must swap it in place.
F.e. you are given:
0 3 1 2
9 2 3 4
5 6 5 7
7 8 9 9

You need to return:
0 3 5 6
9 2 7 8
1 2 5 7
3 4 9 9

If we have matrix 5x5:
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
3 8 7 5 0
3 1 7 8 5
7 4 3 6 7

We still have to swap 2x2 squares, so the result will be:
1 2 3 3 1
6 7 8 7 4
3 8 7 5 0
4 5 7 8 5
9 1 3 6 7

I've figured out that we'll have two variants of this function depending on matrix size: if n is even or uneven.  I've tried to solve this task in two loops but i understand that i just swap elems (it's a variant for an even size):
def Swap4(m,r):
    k = r//2
    if r % 2 != 0:
       for i in range(0, k):
            for j in range(k+1, r):
                t = m[i][j]
                m[i][j] = m[j][i]
                m[j][i] = t
    else:
        for i in range(0, k):
            for j in range(k, r):
                t = m[i][j]
                m[i][j] = m[j][i]
                m[j][i] = t

here k is matrix size n // 2.
However, it looks to me that we need a kind of shift in i loop for indices as we swap elems like this:
[0][2] -> [2][0]
[0][3] -> [2][1]
[1][2] -> [3][0]
[1][3] -> [3][1]


So what's your question?

m[i][j] = m[j][i] is not correct.

For instance, in your example matrix, you should swap m[0][3] with m[3][1], not m[3][0].

Your code is swapping with mirror images along the diagonal.

In the example of a 4x4 matrix, the upper right 2x2 area is swapped with the lower left 2x2 area. However, what would happen with a 5x5 matrix? Would it still swap 2x2 areas, or is the size of the areas to swap supposed to be a parameter to the function?

What is the allowable range for n?

I do not have strict restictions for n, howeever, as it is more academic task, size can be restricted up to 10x10.  Besides, if we have a 5x5 matrix we should still swap 2x2 squares.

@Barmar but swapping m[0][3] with m[3][1] will place top right element to the last row of the matrix, however it should be situated in m[2][1].

You're right, I miscounted.

You don't need a loop, but with a (nested) loop you can avoid having an extra copy of part of the array temporarily, which can matter if your array is enormous and you have memory restrictions that matter.
Note: in a comment, you noted that you couldn't use numpy, something that I missed about your question. I've added a solution with only lists at the end.
Here:
import numpy as np


def swap_quad_copy(m: np.array, n: int) -> None:
    assert (m.shape[0] == m.shape[1]) and n <= m.shape[0] // 2

    o = m.shape[0] - n
    x = m[0:n, o:].copy()
    m[0:n, o:] = m[o:, 0:n]
    m[o:, 0:n] = x


def swap_quad_loop(m: np.array, n: int) -> None:
    assert (m.shape[0] == m.shape[1]) and n <= m.shape[0] // 2

    o = m.shape[0] - n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            m[i, o+j], m[o+i, j] = m[o+i, j], m[i, o+j]


def main():
    m = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24], [31, 32, 33, 34], [41, 42, 43, 44]])
    print(m)

    swap_quad_copy(m, 2)
    print(m)

    swap_quad_loop(m, 2)
    print(m)


main()

The swap_quad_copy shows how you can copy one quad (the upper right one) to a temporary variable, then overwrite that area with the other quad (the lower left one), and then overwrite the other with the temporary variable.
The swap_quad_loop shows how to do the same thing in place, with a nested loop. This takes a bit more time, but uses less space.
Output:
[[11 12 13 14]
 [21 22 23 24]
 [31 32 33 34]
 [41 42 43 44]]
[[11 12 31 32]
 [21 22 41 42]
 [13 14 33 34]
 [23 24 43 44]]
[[11 12 13 14]
 [21 22 23 24]
 [31 32 33 34]
 [41 42 43 44]]

Note that this doesn't work:
m[0:2, 2:4], m[2:4, 0:2] = m[2:4, 0:2], m[0:2, 2:4]

The reason you can swap single elements but not whole slices is that a single element doesn't get you a reference, and the tuple assignment just becomes a normal variable swap. But the slicing operation returns views of the original array, not copies, and thus the copy ends up overwriting one of the quads, and you end up with duplicate data, something like:
[[11 12 31 32]
 [21 22 41 42]
 [31 32 33 34]
 [41 42 43 44]]

If you limit the problem and solution to only using lists of lists, the swap_quad_loop solution still works with minor changes for the type and looks like this:
def swap_quad_loop2(m: list[list[int]], n: int) -> None:
    assert (all(len(m) == len(xs) for xs in m)) and n <= len(m) // 2

    o = len(m) - n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            m[i][o+j], m[o+i][j] = m[o+i][j], m[i][o+j]


def main():
    xss = [[11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24], [31, 32, 33, 34], [41, 42, 43, 44]]
    swap_quad_loop2(xss, 2)
    print('\n'.join(map(str, xss)))


main()

Output:
[11, 12, 31, 32]
[21, 22, 41, 42]
[13, 14, 33, 34]
[23, 24, 43, 44]


It was my bad that I didn't mention that we shouldn't use any modules and wrote it only after i editet the question but thanks to @Grismar solution I've managed to solve this task with just basic python, so I'll mark it as an answer to my question.

Ah I see, you're right - because you said 'matrix' I assumed the use of numpy but you were talking about a list of lists. swap_quad_loop should generally work for a list of list as well. I'll update the answer for anyone that finds your question and looks at my answer, to avoid confusion.
